# Trying to override WordPress admin styles (load-styles.php)

Tags: wordpress-theming

I did exactly what @riddleMeThis [recommended here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/314541/143329), but WordPress is not reading in the styles. What am I missing?

Child theme `functions.php`

```
// Add styles for admin page - event edit table looks terrible after adding columns for custom taxo's
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_styles');

function admin_styles() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom-editor-style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />';
}
```

`custom-editor-style.css`, located in child theme directory (same dir as `style.css`)

```
table.fixed {
    table-layout: auto !important;
}
```

Theoretically this should override the table.fixed declaration in load-styles.php, unless that php file is loaded after my add_action() call... TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly locating the style sheet, as its path is wrong.

```
// Add styles for admin page - event edit table looks terrible after adding columns for custom taxo's
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_styles');

function admin_styles() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-editor-style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Best Way using wp_enqueue_style

```php
function admin_styles() { 
$ver = rand();
wp_enqueue_style('adminStyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin.css',[],$ver );

}
```